# Getting Website data on android app

Tags: android

I am trying to obtain the data of my website in my android app. I tried it with the following code, the application launches and then simple activity_main.xml is displayed with Loading data on the screen. I am attaching my code, please guide me.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.httpexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    TextView httpStuff;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        httpStuff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHttp);
        GetMethodEx test = new GetMethodEx();
        String returned;
        try
        {
            returned = test.getInternetData();
            httpStuff.setText(returned);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

GetMethodEx.java:

```
package com.example.httpexample;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class GetMethodEx 
{
    public String getInternetData() throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String data = null;
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            URI website = new URI("http://www.hashmedia.in");
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(website);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String l = "";
            String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((l = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(l + nl);
            }
            in.close();
            data = sb.toString();
            return data;
        }
        finally
        {
            if(in!=null)
            {
                try
                {
                    in.close();
                    return data;
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.httpexample.MainActivity" >

  <ScrollView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">  

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHttp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Loading Data" />

  </ScrollView>  

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: The exact problem is I want to see the data of my website on the android app but only the blank screen is displayed without any info to display.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please suggest where do I exactly write this code ? That will be a great help.

Comment: r u get your website via intent?

Comment: Yes i am able to get my website via intent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple, website view via intent,**

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://www.hashmedia.in"));
startActivity(viewIntent);
```

use this simple code toview your website in android app.

**If you want get particular data use the webservice using JSON.**

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

**Add internet permission in manifest file,**

```
<
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: This is taking user to browser, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

blank screen? have you defined the INTERNET permission into your manifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this:

**youlayout.xml**

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

**yourcode.java**

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.hashmedia.in");
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: Hope this may help you!